# Consuming a SOAP web service (Kronos SaasHR) and saving response into SQL server

Tags: c#, xml, soap, wsdl, kronos-workforce-central

I have been working on a project to connect to our time reporting vendor's SOAP service and get a report weekly (REST doesn't offer function call for getting the desired report). They have only given us the WSDL which has not been helpful: https://secure.entertimeonline.com/ta/padnos.wsdl and 
https://secure.saashr.com/ta/PADNOS.soap

I have added the service reference to my solution and generated the proxy class, but each time I try to fetch the data, I get errors saying "*Response is not well-formed XML.*" and "*data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.*"

This is my first foray into consuming a web service and I cannot find any helpful material.

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // service reference
    // runReportByName
    TSPHoursWorked.ServiceReference1.runReport_ByNameType rptName = new ServiceReference1.runReport_ByNameType();
    rptName.version = 1;
    rptName.reportCategory = "Calculated Time";
    rptName.reportName = "Calculated Time By Entry";
    rptName.reportSavedName = "DailyHoursWorked";
    rptName.outputType = TSPHoursWorked.ServiceReference1.runReport_ByNameTypeOutputType.XML;


    TSPHoursWorked.ServiceReference1.SaaSHRClient soap = new ServiceReference1.SaaSHRClient();
    soap.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
    soap.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
    var requestInterceptor = new InspectorBehavior();
    soap.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(requestInterceptor);
    soap.runReport_ByName(rptName);
    string requestXML = requestInterceptor.LastRequestXML;
    outputText.Text = requestXML;
    string responseXML = requestInterceptor.LastResponseXML;
    outputText.Text += responseXML;
}

public class InspectorBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public string LastRequestXML
    {
        get
        {
            return myMessageInspector.LastRequestXML;
        }
    }

    public string LastResponseXML
    {
        get
        {
            return myMessageInspector.LastResponseXML;
        }
    }


    private MyMessageInspector myMessageInspector = new MyMessageInspector();
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {

    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }


    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(myMessageInspector);
    }
}

public class MyMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public string LastRequestXML { get; private set; }
    public string LastResponseXML { get; private set; }
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        LastResponseXML = reply.ToString();
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        LastRequestXML = request.ToString();
        return request;
    }
}
```

I would just like help simply connecting to their web service, and get the report and bulk insert into SQL server. Could anyone set me on the right path?

**EDIT**:

I've installed SoapUI and there are no URLs listed under the soap operation "Actions" column:[image: no soap actions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with our middle-man vendor to Kronos not having any technical knowledge. After a few weeks and finally getting in touch with Kronos, I was informed that:

- a new user must be created **without single sign-on**
- copy the groups/reports/etc of the main admin account to the new account
- add highest security  privilege to new account

Then you will be able to call the RESTful service. I hope this helps someone because our vendor wasted 2 weeks of our time